# bash shell how to cut the first column out of a file

Tags: bash, shell, cut

so I have a file named 'file' that contains these characters

```
a 1 z
b 2 y
c 3 x
```

how can I cut the first column and put it in it's own file?

I know how to do the rest using the space as a delimiter like this:

```
cut -f1 -d ' ' file > filecolumn1
```

but I'm not sure how to cut just the first column since there isn't any character in the front that I can use as a delimiter.

Comment: Why do you need a chacter in front of it? The `-d` option specifies the delimiter, which is between the columns. Just use `-f1` to get the first column.

Comment: when I use cut -f1 file > filecolumn1 it keeps everything from file

Comment: Because you left out the delimiter, which defaults to TAB, not SPACE.

Answer (score 4):

The delimiter doesn't have to be before the column, it's **between** the columns. So use the same delimiter, and specify field 1.

```
cut -f1 -d ' ' file > filecolumn1
```

Comment: oh dang, thanks!  I don't know what I was doing wrong earlier, but it wasn't working for me lol, it is now though, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Barmar's got a good option. Another option is awk:

```
awk '{print $1}' file > output.txt
```

If you have delimiter, you could use `-F` switch and provide a delimiter. For example, if your data was like this:

```
a,1,2
b,2,3
c,3,4
```

you can use awk's `-F` switch in this manner:

```
awk -F',' '{print $1}' file > output.txt
```